# How to match everything before an underscore in class names and replace with a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qs5HY/12/)**

The table has class names like:

`dsdds_image`,`dfdd_image`,`sdadsa_title`,`dsdf_title`,`3434_description`,`48fd_description`.

They are just random strings before the underscore. How would you replace all these random strings with the word "placeholder" in jQuery so that they become `placeholder_title`,`placeholder_image`,`placeholder_description`?

HTML:

```
<button id="cleartable">Clear</button>
<table class="toptable">
  <tr>
    <th class="dsdds_image">1</th>
    <th class="r3dde_image">2</th>
    <th class="s43434_image">3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="44665_description">4</td>
    <td class="3434d_description">5</td>
    <td class="a34df_description">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dfs4rf_title">7</td>
    <td class="adf43df_title">8</td>
    <td class="dsffds4_title">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My failed attempt

```
$("#cleartable").click(function() {
  $(".toptable td,.toptable th").each(function() {
    var changeclass = $(this).attr("class");
    changeclass.replace(/^[^_]+/,"placeholder");    
  });
});
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, `replace` doesn't mutate the original string.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
$("#cleartable").click(function() {
   $(".toptable td,.toptable th").each(function() {
     var changeclass = $(this).attr("class");
     $(this).attr('class',changeclass.replace(/^[^_]+/,"placeholder"));//See this?  
   });
});
```

`.replace` gives you a new string and will not change the original. So, you'll need to reassign it somewhere.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I don't have Ubuntu account. So, I can't chat there.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, come over here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54375/avinash-raj-and-me

Answer (score 1):

Something like this seems a lot easier

```
$('#cleartable').on('click', function () {
    $('td, th', '.toptable').attr('class', function(_, klass) {
        return 'placeholder_' + klass.split('_').pop();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qs5HY/13/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
$("#cleartable").click(function() {
    $(".toptable td,.toptable th").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("class", changeclass.replace(/^[^_]+/,"placeholder"));    
    });
});
```

As you were not assigning the replaced class back to the elements picked